# I want delete a Package in my iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode

i add package once!
but since that i dont need that package
so i try to delete that
i can not delete!!
many friends told me you can delete in Package Dependencies and click "-"
but i cant find my package what i added.....

Oh! and this thing is keep follow like zombies.......when i create git branch....
in Package.resolved file...

help me plz

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnwZq.png)
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gw92k.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcSCR.png)

xcode turn on / off
but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the package in the "Swift Packages" tab:

- Check the project files directly: the package was not added through Xcode's package manager. In that case, you can always check the project files directly (e.g.,.xcodeproj or .xcworkspace files) for any references to the package and you can remove them manually.
- Check projects source code and build settings: ensure that the package has been    properly removed from your project's source code and build settings.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

1.select your project

2.tab Package Dependencies

3.select package and remove it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To remove package dependancies from your project follow below steps.

1. Click on Project Name
2. Select your project ( not target )
3. Choose package dependencies tab
4. Click on package which you want to remove
5. Click on - button

plz check screenshot for ref

[image]